# MS Access Merge .mdb to .accdb take too much time

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2003

We are currently merging our Access DB from 2003 to 2016 (mdb to accdb). However the import process takes approximately 4 hours to complete. While hundreds of tables, modules and forms takes only 15 minutes to import, the queries takes 3.5 hours.

Because of our system requirements, this importing process (importing all elements from accdb to another accdb) will be repeated every 3 days. Our current import process (mdb to mdb) takes approximately 20-30 mins to complete which is fine. But, after we convert to Access 2016 this timing issue will cause us some problem. Perhaps there is a settings about importing queries that I don't know ?

Comment: Do you [Split your Access database into data and application](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-01.html)? are you sure you need this process for both ends?

Comment: When you import a query, are you importing the query's definition or the data set which is returned by the query?

Comment: @marlan No, our database is in one piece. There is no linked db files.

Comment: @HansUp On the import menu, for queries there is two options. Import Queries `As Queries` and `As Tables`. I'm choosing import `As Queries`.

Comment: I don't understand why it takes so long then.  Have you finished importing all the tables before you import the queries?

Comment: @HansUp what happens is, access imports tables then skips queries, imports forms, import modules and at the end starts importing queries. However what I understand from the information that is provided on the bottom, the queries are being searched in VBA modules and being updated for some reason. That is what takes so long.

Comment: Not sure what is going on, but that sounds like Track Name Autocorrect may be involved.  In the destination database, suggest you go to Access Options, Current Database, and  uncheck those options under the Name AutoCorrect Options heading.   Does that allow you to import the queries faster?

Comment: @HansUp I`ll try what you suggest.

Comment: @HansUp Thank you very much. You saved us from a big problem. Those check boxes were exactly the reason it took so much time. Currently I was able to import everything within 17 minutes. Please provide it as the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you reported Access checks/revises modules while importing queries, that made me wonder if *Track Name Autocorrect* could be involved.

So I suggested you open the destination database, go to Access Options and select *"Current Database"*.  Then under the *"Name AutoCorrect Options"* heading, ensure the related checkboxes are unchecked.  (In Access 2010, there are 3 checkboxes under that heading.  I don't know whether that has changed for Access 2016.)  After clicking *"OK"* to save the changes, close and reopen the database.

You reported disabling all the *Track Name Autocorrect* options allowed you to import the queries much faster.

Originally my suggestion was no more than a wild guess.  I avoid using *Track Name Autocorrect* because it is known to cause weird behavior (see [Failures caused by Name AutoCorrect](http://allenbrowne.com/bug-03.html)), so was uncertain whether it could be involved during imports.  Since you found it can be involved, I'll take that as another reason to avoid *Track Name Autocorrect*.  :-)

If you ever need to do mass renaming in your database, you could enable *Track Name Autocorrect*, do the renaming, and disable *Track Name Autocorrect* again afterward.  But leaving it enabled all the time seems unwise to me.